# What is the product of the reaction of diol with tosyl chloride followed by lithium aluminum hydride?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution, organic-reduction

[image]

This question is about the structure of products X and Y.
According to me, the answer should be only A (as OTs will substitute on benzylic carbon).

But in the answer key, they have given B and D.

Please help.

Comment: I'd suggest you that, in your future questions and answers, not to abbreviate word for the benefit of most of the readers. Thank you.

Comment: Done @MathewMahindaratne. Will keep this in mind for future questions...

Comment: The picture is blurry. Please upload a better quality one/ consider sketching through chemsketch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two replaceable $\ce{H}$s in the starting material, but only 1 equiv of $\ce{TsCl}$ is given. Thus, primary $\ce{-OH}$ will win the battle due to steric reasons, and therefore, B represent the intermediate product X. The second reaction is firstly acid-base reaction between secondary $\ce{-OH}$ and $\ce{H-}$, and then, nucleophilic substitution ($\mathrm{S_N}$2) reaction to replace $\ce{-OTs}$ group by $\ce{H-}$. That leaves D as the product Y, after acid workup.

Comment: So u mean that since the benzylic carbon is sterically hindered, its  -OH won't be substituted??

Comment: The faster reaction is acid-base reaction. Once, acetic $\ce{H}$ removed from $\ce{-OH}$, it is basically not removable.